# Show all values for a field collection in node.tpl.php

Tags: theming, entities

I have a problem with theming field collection. I want to create a loop and I have a field called field_earth inside field_helloworld that displays unlimited images. The following code doesn't show any image.

```
<?php
  $counter = 1;
  foreach ($node->field_helloworld['und'] as $key => $value) {
    $field_collection = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($value['value']));
    $idx = $value['value'];
?>
  <p>
    <small><?php print $counter; ?></small>
    <?php print $field_collection[$idx]->field_venus['und'][0]['value'];?>
  </p>
  <div>
    <?php print $field_collection[$idx]->field_earth['und']['0'][value];?>
  </div>
  <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php  } ?>
```

Can anyone show me how to display all images?

Answer (score 3):

```
/**
 * @Show all field collection values from node object
 *  Example field collection name: "field_helloworld"
 *  Example fields within a field collection:
 *  - field_title       (string)
 *  - field_image       (image)
 *  - field_description (string)
 */


// get field collections from node 
$field_helloworld = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_helloworld');

// get all fields values if collection exists
if (!empty($field_helloworld)){
    $field = field_view_value('node',$node, 'field_helloworld', $field_helloworld[0]);  
    foreach ($field['entity']['field_collection_item'] as $id => $field_collection){

        // load the field collection item entity
        $field_collection_item = field_collection_item_load($id);
        // wrap the entity and make it easier to get the values of fields
        $field_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $field_collection_item);

        // all values from a field collection
        $field_title        = $field_wrapper->field_title->value();
        $field_image        = $field_wrapper->field_image->value(); // an array of image data
        $field_description  = $field_wrapper->field_description->value(); 

        // an example of getting image url from field_image
        $image_url          = $field_image['uri'] ? file_create_url($field_image['uri']) : '';
    }
}
```

Notice that there is no `['und']['0'][value]`.

Answer (score 2):

I have a node with a field collection called "field_table." I used `field_collection_item_load()` to get all the values inside it. You can get all URIs inside an array, and loop to display the images.

```
 $node = node_load(71); // This is the node containing the field collection.
 $arr = array();

 foreach ($node->field_table['und'] as $oneRow) {
   $row = field_collection_item_load($oneRow['value']);
   $arr[] = array(
     'image' => $row->field_img['und'][0]['uri']
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The title of this question is *Show all values for a field collection in node.tpl.php*...

Add this to your `node.tpl.php` file to dump all the output:

```
  print '<pre>' . check_plain(print_r($content, 1)) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php print image_style_url("thumbnail", $field_collection[$id]->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);?>">
```

Use image_style_url and it will work. field_image is the machine name for image field.