# How to get field collection value in tpl file in drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, theming, entities

I have created a content type and take field collection for some field. Within field collection I have taken 4 select box. Now I need to get these select box value in content type tpl file. For this I am using this code : `$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node_data);`

but its not giving me select box option value.

Comment: Do you want to show the select box in the back office template ? What's the name of your .tpl files ?

Comment: refer [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/how-do-i-load-a-field-collection-from-a-node)

Comment: check this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26433/show-all-values-for-a-field-collection-in-node-tpl-php

Answer (score 2):

Use `entity_load('field_collection_item', array($item_id))` or `field_collection_field_get_entity($item)`

Sample

```
$node = node_load($id);
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_fc');
foreach ($items as $item) {
$fc_value = field_collection_field_get_entity($item);
// Do something.
}
```

For reference [link 1](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11062/how-do-i-load-a-field-collection-from-a-node), [link 2](https://www.drupal.org/node/1166238)

Answer (score 1):

Simple render the field on the `node.tpl.php` with field machine name:

```
print render($content['field_collection']);
```

It's work for me.